# Gstreamer1.0 missing plugin: decodebin2 in Python code

Tags: plugins, gstreamer, python-gstreamer

The following Python code that adds three files to a GES timeline throws up the following error that others have also had:

(GError('Your GStreamer installation is missing a plug-in.',), 'gstdecodebin2.c(3928): gst_decode_bin_expose (): /GESPipeline:gespipeline0/GESTimeline:gestimeline0/GESVideoTrack:gesvideotrack0/GnlComposition:gnlcomposition1/GnlSource:gnlsource0/GstBin:videosrcbin/GstURIDecodeBin:uridecodebin0/GstDecodeBin:decodebin4:\nno suitable plugins found')

```
from gi.repository import GES
from gi.repository import GstPbutils
from gi.repository import Gtk
from gi.repository import Gst
from gi.repository import GObject
import sys
import signal

VIDEOPATH = "file:///path/to/my/video/folder/"

class Timeline:
    def __init__(self, files):
    print Gst._version # prints 1

    self.pipeline = GES.Pipeline()
    container_caps = Gst.Caps.new_empty_simple("video/quicktime")
    video_caps = Gst.Caps.new_empty_simple("video/x-h264")
    audio_caps = Gst.Caps.new_empty_simple("audio/mpeg")
    self.container_profile = GstPbutils.EncodingContainerProfile.new("jane_profile", "mp4 concatation", container_caps, None )#Gst.Caps("video/mp4", None))

    self.video_profile = GstPbutils.EncodingVideoProfile.new(video_caps, None, None, 0)
    self.audio_profile = GstPbutils.EncodingAudioProfile.new(audio_caps, None, None, 0)
    self.container_profile.add_profile(self.video_profile)
    self.container_profile.add_profile(self.audio_profile)

    self.bus = self.pipeline.get_bus()
    self.bus.add_signal_watch()
    self.bus.connect("message", self.busMessageCb)

    self.timeline = GES.Timeline.new_audio_video()
    self.layer = self.timeline.append_layer()
    signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, self.handle_sigint)
    self.start_on_timeline = 0

    for file in files:
        asset = GES.UriClipAsset.request_sync(VIDEOPATH + file)
        print asset.get_duration()
        duration = asset.get_duration()
        clip = self.layer.add_asset(asset, self.start_on_timeline, 0, duration, GES.TrackType.UNKNOWN)
        self.start_on_timeline += duration
        print 'start:' + str(self.start_on_timeline)

    self.timeline.commit()
    self.pipeline.set_timeline(self.timeline) 

def handle_sigint(self, sig, frame):
    Gtk.main_quit()

def busMessageCb(self, unused_bus, message):
    print message
    print message.type
    if message.type == Gst.MessageType.EOS:
        print "eos"
        Gtk.main_quit()
    elif message.type == Gst.MessageType.ERROR:
        error = message.parse_error()
        print (error)
        Gtk.main_quit()


if __name__=="__main__":
   GObject.threads_init()
   Gst.init(None)
   GES.init()
   gv = GES.version() # prints 1.2

   timeline = Timeline(['one.mp4', 'two.mp4', 'two.mp4'])
   done = timeline.pipeline.set_render_settings('file:///home/directory/output.mp4', timeline.container_profile)
   print 'done: {0}'.format(done)
   timeline.pipeline.set_mode(GES.PipelineFlags.RENDER)
   timeline.pipeline.set_state(Gst.State.PAUSED)
   Gtk.main()
```

I have set the GST_PLUGIN_PATH_1_0 environment variable to "/usr/local/lib:/usr/local/lib/gstreamer-1.0:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gstreamer-1.0"

I compiled and installed gstreamer1.0-1.2.4, together with the base,  good, bad and ugly packages for that version. GES is installed with version 1.2.1 as this was the nearest to the gstreamer version I found. I also installed the libav-1.2.4.

The decodebin2 should be in base according to the make install log for plugin-base and is linked into libgstplayback, which is part of my GST_PLUGIN_PATH_1_0:

```
   /usr/local/lib/gstreamer-1.0 libgstplayback_la-gstdecodebin2.lo
```

I do have gstreamer0.10 and the decodebin2 is there as a blacklisted version when I do 'gst-inspect-1.0 -b' as it sits in the gstreamer0.10 library path rather than on that for 1.0.

I tried clearing the ~/.cache/gstreamer files and running gst-inspect-1.0 again to regenerate the plugin registry but I still keep getting the error in the Python code. This sample code might be wrong as it is my first stab at writing a timeline using Gstreamer editing services. I am on Ubuntu Trusty or 14.04.

The file is an mp4 file which is why I installed gst-libav for the required libraries. 
The output of MP4Box -info on the file is:

- Movie Info *
  Timescale 90000 - Duration 00:00:08.405
  Fragmented File no - 2 track(s)
  File suitable for progressive download (moov before mdat)
  File Brand mp42 - version 0
  Created: GMT Mon Aug 17 17:02:26 2015

  File has no MPEG4 IOD/OD

  Track # 1 Info - TrackID 1 - TimeScale 50000 - Duration 00:00:08.360
  Media Info: Language "English" - Type "vide:avc1" - 209 samples
  Visual Track layout: x=0 y=0 width=1920 height=1080
  MPEG-4 Config: Visual Stream - ObjectTypeIndication 0x21
  AVC/H264 Video - Visual Size 1920 x 1080
  AVC Info: 1 SPS - 1 PPS - Profile Main @ Level 4.2
  NAL Unit length bits: 32
  Pixel Aspect Ratio 1:1 - Indicated track size 1920 x 1080
  Self-synchronized

  Track # 2 Info - TrackID 2 - TimeScale 48000 - Duration 00:00:08.405
  Media Info: Language "English" - Type "soun:mp4a" - 394 samples
  MPEG-4 Config: Audio Stream - ObjectTypeIndication 0x40
  MPEG-4 Audio MPEG-4 Audio AAC LC - 2 Channel(s) - SampleRate 48000 Synchronized on stream 1

log @ [pastebin.com/BjJ8Z5Bd](http://pastebin.com/BjJ8Z5Bd) for when I run 'GST_DEBUG=3,gnl*:5 python ./timeline1.py > timeline1.log 2>&1'

Answer (score 1):

There is no "decodebin2" in GStreamer 1.x, which you're using here. It's just called "decodebin" now and is equivalent to "decodebin2" in 0.10.

Your problem here however is not that decodebin is not found. Your problem is that you're missing a plugin to play this specific media file. What kind of media file is it?

Comment: Hi Sebastian, Great to hear from you as I recognise your name as a key contributor to the Gstreamer project, and  I hope Gstreamer will become a foundation for my work with video. The MP4 details from MP4Box are added to my question. Why is my code then asking for Gstreamer0.10-based elements?

Comment: Tried changing the container_caps to 'video/mpeg'  (also setting 'version' to 4) from 'video/quicktime'. However, the 'timeline.pipeline.set_render_settings('file:///home/ian/output.mp4', timeline.container_profile)' returns false and nothing is played.

Comment: It's not asking for 0.10 elements. Not sure where you see it asking for decodebin2 :)

The problem is not the output format, but the problem is reading the input file and decoding it. What kind of input file do you use? You might also miss something for the output, but it's not even at that point yet.

Comment: Maybe I am reading too literally the error msg: '...gstdecodebin2.c(3928)... ? I thought GES would build the pipeline for me and since gst-launch-1.0 playbin uri=file:///path/to/my.mp4' on the command line works fine, I would have thought the Python code would do too.

Comment: If gst-launch-1.0 works with playbin on the file, GES should too. Impossible to know more without a full debug log here.

But you are reading that error too literal. gstdecodebin2.c(3928) is the source file and line where this error is produced, and this error says that a plugin is missing that is needed here. From a debug log it should be visible what is missing.

Comment: Hi Sebastian,  I have a log for you @ pastebin.com/BjJ8Z5Bd for when I run 'GST_DEBUG=3,gnl*:5 python ./timeline1.py > timeline1.log 2>&1'. Could 'ges ges-asset.c:774:ges_asset_request:[00m Tried to create an Asset for type GESUriClip but no ->init method' be a clue? This happens for each clip I have. Odd as the duration of clip is printed correctly when I run the code.

Comment: I was thinking of a full log with GST_DEBUG=6

Comment: Ok thanks, it is 35 Mb though.  [log with GST-DEBUG=6](http://www.blipstation.com/log/timeline-debug6.log)

Comment: Best to report this here https://bugzilla.gnome.org/enter_bug.cgi?product=GStreamer it looks like a bug to me